# MOSS 2007 Trial edition and CAL's pricing 

Tags: 2007, licensing

I wanted to know if I have to buy SharePoint (MOSS) 2007 enterprise CAL's (around 100 users) if I am using MOSS trial software, anybody know anything about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to purchase CALs for trial software, but you are not supposed to be using it in a production environment I don't believe.  Is the 2007 trial software still available and functional?  Seems a little late to be trying the previous version, if you are thinking about implementing anything now I would start by looking at 2010.

Comment: 2007 trail software is still available and Functional. Six months down the line we are going to go to 2010 . I will wait for the first sp to come out for 2010 .. that just me .
thanks for your input appreciate it